# Relation between statistical randomness, uniform distribution and independence

Tags: monte-carlo, randomness

In Monte Carlo simulation, we often consider how well a sequence of generated points are. If I am correct, one aspect is [statistical randomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness):

> A numeric sequence is said to be statistically random when it contains no recognizable patterns or regularities; sequences such as the results of an ideal dice roll, or the digits of π exhibit statistical randomness.

I was wondering if a sequence is statistically random, then does it mean that

- when the points in the sequence are viewed as realizations of a random variable, the random variable has a uniform distribution?
- when different points in the sequence are viewed as realizations of different random variables, the random variables are independent or even i.i.d.?

Does statistical randomness have anything to do with uniform distribution and independence?

Thanks and regards!